# How to use "get-PnPdevice" to get InstanceID of a device

Tags: powershell, scripting, device, instanceid

I want to get the instanceID of a device just as a string and assign it to a variable

I only know the device name, so when I do:

```
Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName 'TSP100'
```

It displays:

```
Status     Class           FriendlyName       InstanceId                                                              
------     -----           ------------      ------------                                                               
OK         PrintQueue      TSP100            SWD\PRIN...
```

so ideally it would look something like this:

```
$env:tsp100id = (Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName 'TSP100' *some stuff*)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just ask for the property, like this...

```
# Assign the first instanceId of the target device to a variable
$env:tsp100id = Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName 'Generic USB Hub' | 
Select-Object -Property InstanceId | 
Select-Object -First 1
$env:tsp100id

# Results
<#
@{InstanceId=USB\VID_05E3&PID_0610\8&26FFBCBB&0&1}
#>

# Assign and output to the screen
($env:tsp100id = (Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName 'Generic USB Hub').InstanceId[0])

# Results
<#
USB\VID_05E3&PID_0610\8&26FFBCBB&0&1
#>
```

Also, just curious. 
Why are you assigning this as an environment entry?

As for ...

> Also how would I go about removing the USB\VID_05E3&PID_0610\ and just
>   getting the 8&26FFBCBB&0&1

The simplest way in this case is just split on the backslash. For example:

```
(($env:tsp100id = (Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName 'Generic USB Hub').InstanceId[0]) -split '\\')[-1]
# Results
<#
8&26FFBCBB&0&1
#>
```

This just says split on the backslash and take action on the last one first.

Comment: This will work perfectly, thank you!

We have a few services that need to have that device id for the TSP100 printer and a few of the bootstrapping scripts would use that env variable when first setting up that printer.

Comment: Also how would I go about removing the `USB\VID_05E3&PID_0610\ ` and just getting the `8&26FFBCBB&0&1`

Comment: Hey postanote, the script has been failing ever so often because sometimes the FriendlyName isn't always just 'TSP100', sometimes its got other stuff. Is there any way I can use Regex to solve this issue? something like '*TSP100*'

Comment: Yep, just try '*TSP100*'